# Asp.net MVC SEO Friendly URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to implement a SEO friendly URL for my ASP.NET MVC website.

Currently i have a URL like:

http://www.domain.com/product?id=productid

but now i want to rewrite my URL like:

http://www.domain.com/productname

So please anybody can help me on above...

Comment: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_Routing.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try with below solution. In `global.asax.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "{productName}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" },
    new { productName = UrlParameter.Optional  }
);
```

But you **required to maintain uniqueness** in `productName` and fetch record by that in index action of product controller (i.e in product Controller:

```
public ActionResult index(string productName)
{
     //do something regarding get product by productname
}
```

Answer (score 14):

This is the best article for starters ->
[SEO Friendly URls](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/SEO-Friendly-Routes-with-ASPnet-MVC.aspx) 
The article also explain how to remove the whitespaces and dashes.

Answer (score 9):

You can add a Route to your MVC routing engine in this fashion -

In `Global.asax.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "{controller}/{productId}/{productName}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" },
    new { productId = UrlParameter.Optional , productName = UrlParameter.Optional  }
);
```

This will allow you to have URL like

```
www.domain.com/productid/productname
```

The reason you may or may not be able to achieve

```
www.domain.com/productname
```

is that productname isn't an identifier and cannot be used to lookup a record uniquely. You would need an identifier in the url.

Ex - look at the URL for this question in SO, it has the ID and then appends SEO friendly test.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new route in the Global.asax to handle this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "productId",                  // Route name
        "productId/{id}/{name}",      // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "productId", id = 1234, name = widget }  // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Asp.Net MVC has routing built in, so no need for the Url Rewriter.

more details [here](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/SEO-Friendly-Routes-with-ASPnet-MVC.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following code and past it in. { routes.MapRoute }

```
routes.MapRuote
{
   

       name: "productname",
       routeTempalate: "services {controller}{aciton}{id}
       defaults: new (id = RouteParameter.Optionl;)

}
```

But for you replace the `"routeTemplate"` with your requirements. for you it's will look like this:

```
routeTemplate: "services{controller}/{productname}"
```

I hope this will help you out.